# aggregate returning * as array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have this simple query:

```
delete from public.field
where template_id = 1
returning *
```

This works fine but of course it returns each line individually whereas I need it to return an array of each row edited.

I have this working in another query and it is how I would like to format the output of the delete query:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(fields))) as fields
```

What I cannot work out is how to combine the two without getting a syntax error.

This is in PostgreSQL 9.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
with d as (
      delete from public.field
      where template_id = 1
      returning *
     )
select array_to_json(array_agg(to_json(d)))
from d;
```

This returns the results of the `delete` as a CTE.  The CTE is then used to generate the JSON representation you want.

Comment: I would use `json_agg` instead of `array_to_json(array_agg())`. Is there a difference? The query plan looks identical https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=820e22f56418d840ff789cb26f0d9d07

Comment: No reason from me, I am still learning SQL and just went with the first thing that worked. I'll swap this in, thank you!

Comment: @S-Man . . . That is a question for the OP.  I just kept the same logic as in the question.